# How To Write A Laravel Join Containing A Select Of MySQL User Defined Variables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I require to write a MySQL join statement in Laravel joining a select statement containing user defined MySQL variables. I have tried using ->join(DB::raw()) to no prevail. Using this join statement is the only way I am able to get the output I require. Would appreciate some help!!

```
JOIN (SELECT @curHODRow:=0, @curHOD:=0,@curYearRow:=0, @curYear:=0, @curMonthRow:=0, @curMonth:=0, @curPtypeRow:=0, @curPtype:=0, @curPcodeRow:=0, @curPcode:=0) v
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide an empty closure as the second argument:

```
->join(DB::raw('(SELECT @curHODRow:=0, [...]) v'), function() {})
```

Comment: Thanks, was looking for this fix for a couple days!!

Comment: I have posted another issue. Would appreciate if you could have a look at this as well and help me out.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52922093/laravel-outputs-different-output-than-mysql-query